# Does Sunrise and Sunset affect the weather?

Tags: space, weather

I've been asked to study on any phenomena related to Weather and Climate. While thinking about this, I noticed that each day, there was a small difference on sunrise and sunset. Like, at one day it was 5:58 AM and at the second day, it was 5:40 AM etc. Does this have anything to do with weather or harmful/useful effects on humans/Earth ? Is this change significance for us, if yes, how? (if no, why?)

There are many questions that arise in my mind and I've been studying a lot about Sunrise and Sunset on internet but I can not find any link or reference where I can find the answers of my doubts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The small changes in sunrise and sunset are caused by the tilt of the world, and the changes in light the earth gets causes winter and summer.  It's been going on for millions of years, so there's no real harm there.

One might also note things like the effect of these on thunderstorms, because the thunderstorms come ultimately from the earth's magnetic field, and this can be influenced by the solar wind and the moon.

NASA keeps an eye out for 'solar flares' which, while not part of weather, can cause a nasty shock to society chance one comes our way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information Sir/Mam. I've one more question, do you think that having "Effects of UV Rays on Humans and on Earth" as a topic of the research is good? I've following sub-themes: i) Weather Around You
ii) Impact of Human Activities on Weather and Climate
iii) Weather, Climate and Ecosystems
iv) Weather, Climate - Society and Culture
v) Weather, Climate and Agriculture
vi) Weather, Climate and Health

I'm not sure which title should I choose (that should be under any of the sub-themes except Agriculture and Health)

Comment: Or I was thinking.. "Effect of Weather & Climate Change on Natural Calamities" as the title of my research.

Comment: UV would be a good topic. The magic words here are Ozone Layer and Ozone hole.  What happens is that flurocarbons, which were used in fridges and air-sprays, break down the ozone layer, and extra UV rays cause cancer etc, are not good for our health,